# Data structure for multi-language dictionary

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, data-structures

I am trying to make a multi-language dictionary let us say English - German dictionary.

I think that I need a language class and a word class, but different languages have different word types and verb tenses, for example, in the German language there are different word genders (Masculine, Feminine, Neuter).

now my question is how to represent the different languages in code :

1- language parent class, word parent class 
2- language "a" class, word "inLanguageA" class and different word types and functions 
3- language "b" class, word "inLanguageB" class and different word types and functions

so that I would be able to get wordInLanguageA.meaning(inLanguageB).

and what is the best way to nest the classes for a language for example :

should German be a new class that implements the interface language or a child for the parent class language and what about the word type how can I handle that? 
German has this types ( Noun, Verb, Adjective) and every type should have his own methods and sometimes a relationship could exist between one or two types ("gehen": verb "to go" , "gehend": Adjective "going")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it perfect, then the diferent classes will be your smallest problem since every language has its method to transform a phrase. English always uses SVO, while in german you can twist the phrase around any way you like. In german you will struggle with nominative, accusative, dative and genitive, while english only transforms its words with the genitive. There are incredibly many rules of how those languages work and there is a reason why you can study them at university. I mean not even Google manages to translate 100% correctly.

So as you probably don't need a super-translator for your program, I think it would be easier to just translate all your texts manually and then make a simple Text-class, which can output its text in the language you like.

EDIT:
So if you only want a dictionary, you could make it look like this:

A dictionary

```
public class Dictionary {

    private Word check, it, out;

    Dictionary() {

        check = new Verb("check", "prüfen", "tester");
        it = new Pronoun("it", "es", "le");
        out = new Preposition("out", "hinaus", "dehors");

        try {
            System.out.print(check.translateTo(Language.German));
            System.out.print(it.translateTo(Language.German));
            System.out.print(out.translateTo(Language.German));
        } catch (Exception whatever) {
            whatever.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

A word

```
public abstract class Word {

    private final String english, german, french;

    protected Word(String english, String german, String french) {
        this.english = english;
        this.german = german;
        this.french = french;
    }

    public String translateTo(Language language) throws Exception {
        switch(language) {
        case English:   return english;
        case German:    return german;
        case French:    return french;
        }
        throw new Exception();      //you can write a LanguageNotFoundException
    }
}
```

Diferent types of words

```
public class Verb extends Word {

    protected Verb(String english, String german, String french) {
        super(english, german, french);
    }
}

public class Pronoun extends Word {

    protected Pronoun(String english, String german, String french) {
        super(english, german, french);
    }
}

public class Preposition extends Word {

    protected Preposition(String english, String german, String french) {
        super(english, german, french);
    }
}
```

A language

```
public enum Language {

    English,
    German,
    French;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to make phrases translator it is just a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have classes for words like noun, verb ... and language class that would transform your words for different cases, like class English that extends Language, and, for example class Word with value "write", then you can call method from language class toPastTime(Word "write") -> wrote, or something like this IMHO.